# Adding minutes to Current time from text input error (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

Currently have a text input from users and which to add that to current time and display on the Screen as a text input in HH:mm format.

```
Current Code:-
NSString *strCurrentDate;
NSString *strNewDate;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
strCurrentDate = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Current Time: %@",strCurrentDate);
int minutesToAdd = workingTime.text;
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar 
alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setMinute:minutesToAdd];
NSDate *newDate= [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
[df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
strNewDate = [df stringFromDate:newDate];
NSLog(@"workingtime is :%@",workingTime.text);
NSLog(@"New Date and Time: %@",strNewDate);
crewOutTime.text = strNewDate;
```

However Add's incorrect amount to time When i Change it to int minutesToAdd = 40; to a fixed Value it is correct and works as wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
int minutesToAdd = workingTime.text.intValue;
```

instead of
    int minutesToAdd = workingTime.text;

With your code you are setting your minutesToAdd to a pointer.

Comment: You mean `int minutesToAdd = [workingTime.text intValue];`. It's best not use to property syntax when calling a non-property method.

Comment: Thanks knew it would be something simple just didn't know how to set value.